# Extracting Number from Log File

Tags: regex, parsing, powershell

I'm trying to extract a number from a log file that outputs lines of text like this:

```
1/11/2016 3:26:12 AM 1/11/2016 3:27:00 AM 45.6 A
```

The output from the line is 45.6 A

However, my Regex code is returning the 12 A from 3:26:12 AM. I need it to completely ignore the time number and just output the 45.6 A.

Here's my Regex code:

```
$regex = '\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s+A)'
```

Comment: you have not closed the regex with '$'

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot to anchor the lookeahead at the end of the string:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s+A$)
                    ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gK9nB5/1)

The `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` will match one or more digits optionally followed with a `.` followed with one or more digits (a float value), and the `(?=\s+A$)` lookahead will require one or more whitespace characters with `A` right at the end of the string to appear after the float value.

```
$s = '1/11/2016 3:26:12 AM 1/11/2016 3:27:00 AM 45.6 A'
$rx = '\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s+A$)'
$result = [regex]::Match($s, $rx, 'RightToLeft')
if ($result) { $result.Value; }
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the current input string does not suggest that there maybe `12 A 12 A` in the input, and both falsetru's and my answers should work. However, if the value is always at the end of the string, you should consider using my solution and use the `RightToLeft` modifier with the regex match method (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [word boundary (`\b`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to match only `A`, not `AM`:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s+A\b)
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/pA7jK2/1

Answer (score 0):

if you just need find the last digit with an A in it, try this

```html
(\d+\.\d\sA)
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/cG8eD8/1)